# RSpec Failure/Error: click_link article.title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am facing this error when running an rspec test. I have tried click_link "Title 1" and assigning Article.create to a variable but the same error appears.

```
 Failure/Error: click_link article.title

 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find link "Title 1"
```

comment_spec.rb

```
require "rails_helper"

describe 'navigate' do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  let(:article) do
    Article.create(title: "Title 1", description: "Some description", user_id: user.id)
  end

  before do
    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
  end

  describe 'create' do
    before do
      visit articles_path
    end

    it"permits a signed in user to write a review" do
        click_link article.title
        fill_in "Content", with: "An awesome article"
        click_button "Post"
        expect(page).to have_content("An awesome article")
        expect(current_path).to eq(article_path(article.id))
    end
  end
end
```

spec/factories/user.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "test#{n}@example.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    name 'Tester'
    email { generate :email }
    password "asdfasdf"
    password_confirmation "asdfasdf"
  end
```

EDIT:

article/index.html.erb

```
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
         <% @articles.each do |article| %>
           <%= render 'article', article: article %>
         <% end %>
      </div>
```

_article.html.erb

```
<%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`let` is lazy loading which means that the block is not evaluated until you call it.

```
    before do
      article # calls the block
      visit articles_path
    end
```

An alternative is to use `let!` which is not lazy loading:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe 'navigate' do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let!(:article) do
    Article.create(title: "Title 1", description: "Some description", user_id: user.id)
  end

  before do
    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
  end

  describe 'create' do
    before do
      visit articles_path
    end

    it"permits a signed in user to write a review" do
        click_link article.title
        fill_in "Content", with: "An awesome article"
        click_button "Post"
        expect(page).to have_content("An awesome article")
        expect(current_path).to eq(article_path(article.id))
    end
  end
end
```